# How to create a php page to collect information from a html page

Tags: php, html

I have create a form on a wordpress page, and I'm trying to pass the values of the form to a php page, so I can send an email with that information, but I don't know how to create the php page, in what folder do I have to save the page.

Thank you (fist time using wordpress);

This is my form:
And I have a different page(send-email) that will collect the data.

I know how to do the code for the send-email page..I just nee dto know where to save the php page.

```
<form method="get" action="send-email.php" name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validate()">   
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="name">Name<span id="req">*</span></label><br> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Quantum Management" value=""> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tel">Phone Number<span id="reqTel">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="(999) 123-4567" value=""  >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email<span id="reqEmail">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" value="" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="questions">Questions<span id="reqQuest">*</span></label><br>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" cols="8" id="questions" name="questions" placeholder="Questions" ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="yes">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've added a this hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="your_form_task">` and updated the post URI to `<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>`.

Here is the updated form-

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name<span id="req">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Quantum Management" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tel">Phone Number<span id="reqTel">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="(999) 123-4567" value=""  >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email<span id="reqEmail">*</span></label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" value="" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="questions">Questions<span id="reqQuest">*</span></label><br>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" cols="8" id="questions" name="questions" placeholder="Questions" ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="yes">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="your_form_task">
</form>
```

Note that it is very important. Now here is the function where you can put your logics to handle form data-

```
function the_dramatist_form_post_to_admin() {
    /**
     * At this point, $_GET/$_POST variable are available
     *
     * We can do our normal processing here
     */

    // Sanitize the POST field
    // Generate email content
    // Send to appropriate email
    // Or do whatever you want to do.
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_your_form_task', 'the_dramatist_form_post_to_admin' );
add_action( 'admin_post_your_form_task', 'the_dramatist_form_post_to_admin' );
```

Look here is another important thing, after `admin_post_nopriv_` and `admin_post_` I've glued the `your_form_task` string what we've declared as hidden input value in the form with input name `action`. It's actually pointing the form to be submitted in this function. And `admin_post_nopriv_{$action}` fires on a non-authenticated admin post request for the given action where `admin_post_{$action}` fires on an authenticated admin post request for the given action. Here `$action` is `your_form_task`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, within WordPress you're not creating an entire page in code, but creating templates that WordPress uses to build the pages. You could theoretically point this form at any other page on the site, and write the code that handles the form data in the functions.php file of your active theme or in a plugin.

But I wouldn't bother with all that work, when you can just use a pre-made solution. This sounds like the exact use case for [Contact Form 7](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).